# Менее строгий парсер html/xml

Tags: xml, html, java, синтаксический-анализ

```
    org.w3c.dom.Document doc = (org.w3c.dom.Document) builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBytes("utf-8")));  //See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706493/java-net-malformedurlexception-no-protocol , if don't know why ByteArrayInputStream
```

Вот, так я отдаю на распарсивание документ. Проблема в том, что док не валидный, на столько не валидный, что его нельзя исправить. Я конечно пытался его исправлять, но это бесполезно. Собственно [док](http://ntvplus.ru/tv/schedule.xl?genre=all&channel=3356&date=20.9.2013&date=21.9.2013&date=23.9.2013&date=24.9.2013&date=25.9.2013&date=26.9.2013&date=27.9.2013&date=28.9.2013&time=day)

Решил поменять парсер. Хочется парсер, работающий как браузер - не владино? ну и всё равно!

Собственно вопрос в том, что **подскажите такой нестрогий парсер**

Comment: тока ссылка на док не пашет:)))

Comment: Да, ссылка получилась крута. Исправил

Comment: я наверно под вечер уже плохо соображаю, но что невалидного в доке?

Comment: Если вы просматривали inspect code в хроме, то нечего, т.к. хром всё сам исправляет). А вообще прогоните док по валидатору (ссылку не получается дать из-за особенностей валидатора). Сначало ругается на доктайп. Если добавить доктайп, ругается на прочую хрень

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jsoup не пробовали:
http://jsoup.org/

ЗЫ:
Буквально намедни боролся с типа "xml" использовал обычный StAx, с предварительной обработкой, исправляющей неправильность источника.